# Load many difficult objects in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have old version of hive, below hive 2.0, in this hive version i create a table:

```
create table test (int id, string name, values array<string>)
```

When i add data, i use this query:

```
 insert into table test select 1, 'Sam', array('sql', 'c++', 'c#', 'java')
```

It work, but i need load more then one row in table, like:

```
insert into table select (1, 'Sam', array('sql', 'c++', 'c#', 'java')), (2, 'AN Other', array('paskal'))
```

How i can do this?

Comment: For add this data i use empty table dummy(value string).

Answer (score 0):

Hive doesn't support use UDFs in something like this

```
INSERT INTO TABLE test VALUES  (1, 'Sam', array('sql', 'c++', 'c#', 'java')), (2, 'test1', array('paskal'));
```

you will get something like

```
Unable to create temp file for insert values Expression of type TOK_FUNCTION not supported in insert/values
```

A workaround would be something like this

```
INSERT INTO TABLE test 
select  1, 'Sam', array('sql', 'c++', 'c#', 'java')
union all 
select 2, 'test1', array('paskal');
```